# Viewing link to flag summary when you have not yet helpful flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, profile-page, flag-history

When someone creates a new account on an SE site, and when he/she flags a post for the first time, he/she can't see whether this flag is still active, or got declined, because the "Helpful flags" link only appears when someone has at least one flag marked as helpful. This could be annoying, because if this flag gets rejected, then he/she can't see *why* this flag was rejected (if a specific reason is added).

So, my suggestion is: after someone has flagged one post (and if it's not yet marked as helpful), show a "Helpful flags: 0" link, so people can see whether his/her flag is still active or declined.

Comment: I should add, if the flag is declined or disputed, a link will appear with "Helpful flags: 0" However, before the flag is marked as such (still active) there is no link.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get the link to the summary is explained in ['flag-history' tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flag-history/info) as follows:

> User and moderators can also access the flagging summary page by going to `<siteurl>/users/flag-summary/<userid>`, substituting for the site in question and user ID

Using your ID (229438) at MSO as an example, link to flag history here would be: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/229438 (visible only to you and moderators)